# How can I programmatically force an IAsyncOperation into the error state?

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I have some C++/WinRT code that asynchronously returns a string.   However, some of the internal operations can fail, and when it does, I need to have the IAsyncOperation also move to the error state.  `co_return` obviously moves the operation to the completed state; how can I move the operation to the error state?   The stripped down code follows:

```cpp
winrt::IAsyncOperation<winrt::hstring> MyClass::DoAuthenticationAsync()
{
    auto acctProvider = co_await winrt::WebAuthenticationCoreManager::FindAccountProviderAsync(AccountProviderId, authority, user);
    auto webToken = winrt::WebTokenRequest(acctProvider, CarbonScope, CarbonClientId, winrt::WebTokenRequestPromptType::Default);

    webToken.Properties().Insert(L"authority", authority);
    webToken.Properties().Insert(L"resource", resource);

    auto requestResult = co_await winrt::WebAuthenticationCoreManager::GetTokenSilentlyAsync(webToken);

    auto requestStatus = requestResult.ResponseStatus();
    if (requestStatus == winrt::WebTokenRequestStatus::Success)
    {
        co_return requestResult.ResponseData().GetAt(0).Token();
    }
    else if (requestStatus == winrt::WebTokenRequestStatus::UserInteractionRequired)
    {
        auto uxresult = co_await winrt::WebAuthenticationCoreManager::RequestTokenAsync(webToken);

        requestStatus = uxresult.ResponseStatus();
        if (requestStatus == winrt::WebTokenRequestStatus::Success)
        {
            co_return uxresult.ResponseData().GetAt(0).Token();
        }
    }
    if (requestStatus == winrt::WebTokenRequestStatus::ProviderError)
    {
        // here I'd like to have the IAsyncOperation have an Error status with the ErrorCode from the requestResult.
        auto err = requestResult.ResponseError().ErrorCode();
    }
    co_return L"";
}
```

Comment: You can throw an exception. It gets re-thrown on the thread that issued the `co_await` operator. If the exception crosses the ABI, there's very little fidelity preserved.

Comment: I'd prefer not to throw, as the caller is actually in C++/CX (yay legacy) and has explicitly set a completed handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must throw a `winrt::xxx` or `std::xxx` exception. This will be caught at the coroutine boundary and returned across the ABI to the calling language projection, which will typically rethrow the exception. This is specifically designed to work cross-language.

Comment: So if I throw a `winrt::hresult_error` exception, the caller will get the Completed handler called with a status of `AsyncStatus::Error`?   Or does the caller have to explicitly catch `winrt::hresult_error`?

Comment: Yes, if the caller is explicitly handling the Completed callback then they will be notified of that status by that means. Typically however, the caller will use `co_await async` or `async.get()` to wait on the result and in those cases the exception will be rethrown.

Comment: Since caller is C++/CX, they could use a task-based version of `then()` and check the status of the `task<T>` to avoid having the exception thrown. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/exception-handling-in-the-concurrency-runtime?view=vs-2019)